# Files lost after reboot in Windows

Tags: windows-7, hibernate, ntfs

I have a dual boot OS(Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7) in my laptop. I recently copied some important files from a pen drive to one of my NTFS drives from Ubuntu. After copying i was able to view the files in the directory and hence i formatted the pen drive.

The problem occurred when i rebooted the system in Windows, i could not find any of the files or the folders i copied in the drive. I again rebooted into Ubuntu and could not find it there also.

What is the reason my files got deleted? Is there any way to recover them?

**Note** : For your information my Windows was in hibernation state when i was copying the files in Ubuntu. Will this affect the files in any manner?

Comment: The last time I have attempted to mount an NTFS from an hibernated Windows system it provided a warning and refused to mount, didn't you get such warning ?

Comment: Do you have deep freeze installed in your system(Windows)?

Answer (score 3):

You can't hibernate Windows and then run Ubuntu -- it's very dangerous -- and I think this is the result, the files were deleted or corrupted...

http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/saw27/notes/detect-hibernated-windows-from-linux.html